# override http status with cxf

Tags: java, cxf

I'm using CXF for web services.
Because of some client restrictions, I need all web faults to return code 200 instead of 500.
I tried to use interceptors, depends on the phase I was able to either override the status and then the response is empty or the response is full with the fault but then the status is not overridden.
Any ideas how to do that?
Using interceptors, what would be the right phase?
I registered the interceptor like this:

```
@org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutFaultInterceptors(interceptors = { "com.my.prod.core.service.itercept.HttpStatusInterceptor" })
```

and this is the interceptor:

```
public class HttpStatusInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

public HttpStatusInterceptor(){
    super(Phase.POST_STREAM_ENDING);
}

@Override public void handleMessage(org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage msg) throws org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault{
    msg.put(SoapMessage.RESPONSE_CODE, "200");
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
msg.put(SoapMessage.RESPONSE_CODE, 200);
```

so it ends up as and Integer object instead of a String.   I think it's expecting the integer.

Comment: i do get a response code 200, but the response itself is empty

Comment: now.. is it possible to register this interceptor to all endpoints?